# XMLHttpRequest sends b'' instead of json data

Tags: javascript, json, flask, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send json data from my web app to my python flask api, my server is receiving the `POST` rqeuest & is receiving data, the issue is that it's not receiving json data rather the string `b''`

This is the javascript code I got to send the json data to my api

```js
function onSubmit() {
    document.getElementById("orderbutton").disabled=true;
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("orderbutton").disabled=false;',3000);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/order";
    request.open('POST', url, true)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    request.onload = function() {
        var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
        console.log(response)
    }

    request.send(JSON.stringify({"id": document.getElementById("order").value.trim()}))
}
```

edit: it's not an issue with document.getElementById("order").value.trim() because when I `console.log` it, I get the input I put in my `<input>` field

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your `send()` line to

```
request.send(JSON.stringify({id: document.getElementById("order").value.trim()}));
```

Change is from `"id"` to `id`

Comment: Can you add your server codes here? Not forgetting to mask confidential info.

Comment: `@app.route('/api/order', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def is_valid():
    print(request.get_data())
    unique_id = request.get_json()['id']`

Answer (score 0):

use `.decode('utf-8')`, Let me know the result.